VS Code Golang debugger: how to figure out whether a large array contains any non-zero values
The Debug console of VS Code is displaying a large slice/array like this:
canvas.img.Pix
[]uint8 len: 2073600, cap: 2073600, [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...+2073536 more]


How can you figure out which canvas.img.Pix elements are non-zero?

You could just iterate over the slice and break on the first non-zero value you get. This break statement could in-turn be used to set-up a breakpoint:
v := []byte{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
for _, vv := range v {
    if vv > 0 {
        // use a break statement to set a breakpoint
        break
    }
}


Can I do this on the debug console? I'm not sure.

I'm not sure what you mean with using the debug console. Golang isn't an interpreter language. You can't just execute arbitrary code while on a breakpoint. Setting a breakpoint while checking for a condition by the code is what you want. You may want to look in the documentation for delve (the debugger you're using), however, I'm not aware of any trivial way of doing what you're trying to achieve using the delve API.

Thanks. I'm going to take a look at the delve API maybe.
